# Why did Ego need to return home every now and then?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

In the film Ego explains that he needs to return home every now and then "Otherwise this form would perish". That doesn't seem to be too much of a problem for Ego as during his fight with the guardians he recreates his form multiple times. Why does he waste so much time returning back to the light when he could abandon/let that form perish and just send a new one, essentially reducing travel time by half.

Is there any reasoning behind this?

Comment: Probably for the same reason you wash your socks instead of throwing them in the bin and opening a new pack

Comment: @Valorum If I could magic up socks out of thin air I wouldn't be washing them

Comment: He had a curfew.

Comment: You assume Ego was telling the truth?

Comment: @DisturbedNeo I have considered the possibility of it being a lie but doesn't make much sense to lie about it

Comment: He also contradicts himself by saying if he went to Earth to visit Peter's mother a fourth time, he would have never left.

Answer (score 3):

We know from his early life that he is the planet and not the person. "He" needs to return to the Light because he is basically doing puppetry with 10` poles. He is good at it, but he can't do everything and little errors will eventually accumulate and kill the puppet.

On his surface he is able to do whatever he really feels like and can easily fix anything as it comes up as well as catch up on any deferred maintenance. This is shown by how he states that Peter Quill will also have to return to the planet occasionally if he wants to live forever and the basic principle of Occam's Razor.

Answer (score 1):

The planet is his battery. He sends his form like a feeler or tentacle.

Think of his body as a Roomba and the planet as electric socket with a Roomba charger and memory bank. Body walks around and does useful things but it has limited amount of "Light" energy and memory space. If the body doesn't return to recharge occasionally and make backups of memories in the planet, the memories that particular body had created and the knowledge it had collected since last recharge would perish.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for his forms not being able to transmit the memories back to the light. That sounds like a big assumption otherwise.

Comment: It might be able to transmit them, but my guess is it would use up his light energy and that the expenditure would grow with distance. Easier to just move the whole body around, is my guess. We do know that he wanted to use Peter as a battery, which means that "The Light" can be stored in another person's body. But this is just my understanding of the characters and the scene. I have no proof but Ego's words.